# CPANEL root folder deleted

Tags: cpanel

By mistake I have deleted the root folder which include public_html, ssl , var and all hidden files because I wanted to take a backup as my previous backup has all these folders.

But now I am not able to access my Wp-Admin.

Can someone tell me what should I do in this case?

I was just playing with wordpress, so if someone can point me to fresh install instead of restore that would also be good.

Comment: Try to restore from backup.

Comment: @Raptor I did that, and even after that I a not able to access the wp-admin

Comment: Let us know the error that you facing now.

Comment: cPanel is not related to WordPress at all. They are 2 separate web-based software. Check your web server logs, especially error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the **public_html** folder from a linux shell console:

```
mkdir public_html
chmod 750 public_html
chown cpaneluser:nobody public_html
```

Then restore your files from backup. Be sure that all the files inside the public_html/ folder to have this ownership **cpaneluser:cpaneluser** (where cpaneluser is your account cpanel username)

If you do not want to restore then be sure you have created the **public_html/** folder with the permissions mentioned above and then just reinstall wordpress. You can do that manually using FTP or you can just use Softaculous or any other installer that might be available in your cpanel account.